# Determine using the comparison test whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n^2 + 1}}$ diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How can I determine whether or not the following series converges using the comparison test?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^2 + 1)^\frac{1}{3}}$$

As $n$ goes to infinity, the sum is roughly equal to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^2)^\frac{1}{3}} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\frac{2}{3}}$.

I believe that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n^2 + 1)^\frac{1}{3}} < \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\frac{2}{3}}$ for all $n$.

Using the $p$ test, it is clear that the latter sum diverges. However I cannot say that the former also diverges as the inequality sign does not satisfy the conditions of the comparison test for divergence.

Comment: Does it have to be that comparison test?  Can you use the limit comparison test?

Comment: If you replace $n^3+1$ with the term $n^3+n^3=2n^3\ge n^3+1$ your trick works and you can make the comparison. You just have to take out a constant factor from the sum. This kind of trick can help a lot in simplifying apparently complicated problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $n^2+1 \le 2 n^2$ so you have
${1 \over \sqrt[3]{n^2+1}} \ge {1 \over \sqrt[3]{2}} {1 \over \sqrt[3]{n^2}} $.

Answer (score 3):

By the limit comparison test, we have

$$(\frac{1}{n^2+1})^\frac{1}{3} \sim \frac{1}{n^\frac{2}{3}}\;\; (n\to +\infty)$$

$\frac{2}{3}<1$ thus

$\;\;\;\;\;\sum (\frac{1}{n^2+1})^\frac{1}{3}$ diverges.

Comment: You should add at which point this equivalence is valid.

Comment: Fine! I pointed it because may beginners think $\sim$ means ‘appro ximately equal to’ (which is not a mathematical notion, and is denoted $\approx$) – and physicists often use it in this sense.

Comment: $u_n\sim v_n$ means $u_n=v_n(1+\epsilon(n))$ with lim_{n\to+\infty}\epsilon(n)=0$.

Comment: I has no doubt you know it. The problem was only that it should not be misinterpreted by beginners.